# How to bypass mandatory updates in Brave browser?

Tags: brave

Brave browser refuses to work, opening a message "This version of Brave is unsupported and can no longer be used." There's a "Download Now" button that doesn't install updates.

How do I bypass this behavior and use the browser anyway?

Comment: OS? Updates depend directly on the OS the browser is running. If Linux the updates are managed like all the other system updates.

Comment: You cannot, update it or quit using brave browser.